# Customizing x and y ticks according to a parameter

Tags: matlab, plot, parameters, matlab-figure, axis-labels

Instead of using numerical values to indicate the position where I want ticks, is it possible to say something like:
I want ticks from `-a` to `a` with a spacing between one thick and another of `a/10`? How is it defined, to have the same thing I should use

```
xticks([-a, -9a/10, -8a/10, ..., 0, a/10, 2a/10, ..., a])
```

same for yticks. Can I say it in a different way?

Comment: Is `a` a known value? You can control the tick _text_ and _position_ separately. See [`linspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) and [`xticklabels`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticklabels.html).

Comment: Yes, `a` is a variable that I decide `xticklabels` has the same problem of ticks

Comment: Can you please provide a runnable example code (until the point where you are stuck), and also add a figure with manual labels? I have a hard time understanding your difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what you can do, you should be able to modify it to suit your needs:

```
function q51187098(a, nSteps)
if nargin < 1 
  a = 2;
end
if nargin < 2
  nSteps = 10;
end

figure(); fplot(str2func(['@(x)sin(' num2str(a) '*x)']), [-a a]);
xticks(linspace(-a, a, 2*nSteps + 1));
xticklabels({'-a'; strcat('-a',num2str((nSteps-1:-1:1).'),['/' num2str(nSteps)]); '0';...
                   strcat('a', num2str((1:nSteps-1).'),   ['/' num2str(nSteps)]); 'a'});
```

Which yields:

[image: Kinda what was required]